# Devise Omniauth Facebook works on localhost, but not in Production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have a Rails 5.1 app using Heroku.

I am attempting to use Devise with Omniauth Facebook.  The problem is the fact I have it working perfectly on localhost:3000, but I get an error when trying to either sign-up or login on Production.

Based on the Heroku Logs, it would appear the issue is with callbacks:

```
2018-01-21T22:00:32.492550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/auth/auth/facebook/callback?
code=AQC1IE8y6NsiIlFWhCnG_bdH4MoG7XFkOcGRhl4qUAr-
hZ3e6nxTHJR6mothkNKhlFh0NzueLZRaPEtkKBsHb-
PEWNSou5ZAfCwV_M845DT7WKtdwcU6R84c15a0HVys-
9ml0PKI2Wljgu8CzOBz4uhYdPMlkm6AFAvmR1ZCkJ7UGL9Qpm23VQWe-xJ7uv0mtzc9zOIROQT8fQAUW6WUTbHnl-
SywyS0omFU-XiAq2KaXZpcolO7Hnkk0NEgcssZHuBeO6IBZisQchCjPGXi6VdxFmLFgvyxuxrVlSL79ELELqWxXPdpIjn
GVlx2aIpBV12Gqkm8ocI0JhjFbmoD9CUGpd4v4w5kbdlblN3106bZvw&state=ef00f5f6519d9a51e0d9
4846c6c6739bfea76d3e44b3ec69" 
host=www.gourmetcoffee.london request_id=b177986b-
b27c-450e-9950-4af8ef9359af fwd="2a02:c7d:3dc:8e00:91b:3d48:a2e1:4c1d,162.158.154.234" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=931ms status=500 bytes=1733 protocol=https
```

I have updated my Heroku config vars with the `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET`. and they are also stored in `config/application.yml`

**Gems**

```
#User authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~>4.0'
```

**routes.rb**

```
#authentication
  devise_for :users, path: "auth", controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    unlocks: 'users/unlocks',
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  }
  devise_scope :user do
    delete 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_fb_user_session
  end
```

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  #When a valid user is found, they can be signed in with one of two Devise methods: sign_in or sign_in_and_redirect.

  if @user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect @user#, :event => :authentication this will throw if @user is not activated
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end

def failure
  redirect_to root_path
end


  protected

  # The path used when OmniAuth fails
  def after_omniauth_failure_path_for(scope)
    super(scope)
   end
end
```

**devise.rb**

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: "email", info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name'
```

**Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**

`http://localhost:3000/`, `https://www.gourmetcoffee.london`

**UPDATE**
I have modifed `routes.rb` removing `path: 'auth'`:

```
#authentication
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    unlocks: 'users/unlocks',
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  }
```

Still getting the error though.  Now seems to be a status=304, `not-modified`:

```
2018-01-22T08:21:48.156847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/loginWithFacebook" host=www.gourmetcoffee.london request_id=243e2fd1-42c8-4ae1-8bbb-f398e6e9e02c fwd="2a02:c7d:3dc:8e00:a0a1:a430:c07:150,141.101.107.208" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=322 protocol=https
```

**bundle exec rake routes**

```
user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)                          users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)                 users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook
```

Comment: Have you tried running it locally in the production env or similar? You can use something like ngrok.io or localtunnel.me to map locally. You can then further display errors by changing `config.consider_all_requests_local` to true (and then changing it back to false when it's in production)

Comment: In my facebook valid Oauth redirect uris I have full paths (https://www.whateveryouwant.com/users/auth/facebook/callback). I also noticed in your logs that the path has auth repeated: "/auth/auth/facebook/callback"

Comment: @Pablo I noticed the `auth/auth` where is that set. I have been looking for it.

Comment: I guess path: 'auth' in your routes is the  problem.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo I updated my routes, but still not working.

Comment: Simon. What is the path shown in the log error after changing routes?

Comment: @Pablo from the logs, I now have `path="/users/auth/facebook/callback?`

Comment: And what are your routes. Can you run: bundle exec rake routes? Look for the facebook omniauth path.

Comment: @Pablo just updated the OP with the output

Comment: Simon. I have just logged to www.gourmetcoffee.london using my facebook account, and it works.

Comment: I got my girlfriend to try yesterday and it failed, so thats interesting! I can see you in my user table with values in the Provider and Uid, so that does look all correct. Are you able to log out, and back in again?  I did wonder if there was an issue with an existing account.

Comment: Just created a new FB account, and I've also been able to login perfectly.  Have absolutely no idea what was the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I could login and logout several times without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used multiple "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" like this before. However, I used to face the same problem. I resolved it by replacing localhost by my online domain. Let's double-check this URL again.
Replace:

```
http://localhost:3000/, https://www.gourmetcoffee.london
```

By:

```
https://www.gourmetcoffee.london
```